# Custom UIView in Custom UITableViewCell designed in Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

I am trying to implement some drawing in custom UITableViewCells. To do that, I have added custom UIView subclass to my cell and implemented the drawing in drawRect method of the custom UIView subclass.

Here's my approach:

I have a UITableView with custom UITableViewCells. 
I have subclassed UITableViewCell but the design is implemented directly in my storyboard. The contents of the cell are standard elements (UILabels & UIImageViews) and one custom uiview subclass.

I have set up everything in storyboard using constraints & autolayout.

The custom uiview subclass contains drawing code inside the drawRect method.

The drawing will have to be customized based on some parameters for each UITableViewCell.
Question is, what is the proper way to customize the UIView subclass.

At the moment all I get is a black cube, and I cannot see any drawing... The background color doesn't change and the text does not appear (draw).

EDIT:
In cellForRowAtIndexPath I create the custom UIView using its initWithText: andColor: method:

```
- (instancetype)initWithText:(NSString *)text andColor:(UIColor *)color
{
    NSParameterAssert(text);
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        self.text = text;
        [self setBackgroundColor:color];
    }

    return self;
}


-(void)setBackgroundColor:(UIColor *)backgroundColor
{
    self.circleColor = backgroundColor;
    [super setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    [self.circleColor setFill];
    CGContextAddArc(context, CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMidY(rect),
                CGRectGetWidth(rect)/2, 0, 2*M_PI, YES);
    CGContextFillPath(context);

}

- (void)drawSubtractedText:(NSString *)text inRect:(CGRect)rect
             inContext:(CGContextRef)context
{
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeDestinationOut);

    CGFloat pointSize = 8;
    UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:pointSize];

    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0,
                      (CGRectGetMidY(rect) - (font.lineHeight/2)));

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(rect), font.lineHeight);
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    label.font = font;
    label.text = text;
    label.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    [label.layer drawInContext:context];

    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}
```

Comment: post some code or image of what you are doing and what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You would have given tags in your storyboard for the Label and Image. Use those tags and get the reference of subviews as below

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
//some code
UILabel* cellDate = (UILabel *)[cellRef viewWithTag:1]
UIImageView* imageView = (UIImageView *)[cellRef viewWithTag:2]
//some code
}
```

Comment: This would end up bloating my cellForRowAtIndexPath function. You think it's a good idea to do custom drawing in there?

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is wrong. You already added `UIView` reference in story board `UITableviewCell`. And again you are creating a object for the same custom `UIView` class in `cellForRowIndexpath` method. What you can do is, remove the `UIView` from storyboard and in `cellforrowindexpath` method like shown below.

```
    CustomUIClass * c = [[CustomUIClass alloc] init];
    c.frame = CGRectMake(X, Y, Width, height);
    [cell.contentView addSubview:c];
```

Here add your own frame values to prepare `CGRect`.

Comment: Thank you. Looks like a good start. I'm trying to bypass explicitly setting a frame. Would this work with constraints?

Comment: You have to explicitly set constraints in cellForRowIndexpath method. Or otherwise what you can do is, lets keep your view in storyboard and the new view which you create in cellForRowIndexpath , add it to your storyboard view rather than adding to cell.contentView specified above. If you follow this scenario, the class name of the storyboard should be UIView not your custom view.

Comment: Thx again. Unfortunately I ended up with multiple "layer"s of the same uiview. (the same uiview created multiple times, all instances stacked on top of each other). I am inspecting the view hierarchy with xcode's view debugger...